# Issue Installing Nextcloud Snapd

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, snap, nextcloud

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NextCloud/comments/9w2mzf/simple_tutorial_on_how_to_install_and_use_your/) provides a nice simple tutorial(and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAR0cKKwp9g)) but upon entering the command:

```
snap install nextcloud
```

(even with a sudo prefix) I get the following error:

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/nextcloud: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

How can I fix this?

[image: snapd1]
[image: snapd2]

Comment: It looks like `snapd` is not working.  Is `snapd` installed on your system?  `sudo apt install snapd` if not.  You may also need to reboot if you just installed `snapd`.

Comment: When I ran the command to install it from my guilds I got the same response. `snapd is already the newest version (2.48.3+20.04).`

Comment: Have you rebooted since installation?  You also usually need to use `sudo` to do snap installs.

Comment: It was already installed so yes.

Comment: Check `sudo systemctl status -l snapd` - does it show any error messages in the logs about snaps not starting or such?

Comment: See pics now attached to post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126181/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-cloude11).